# A fast dilation image function in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing

I am going to work on the dilated versions of image superpixels, however `bwmorph` and `imdilate` are very slow for my application. For example the following code snippet takes more than 1 second for N=200 (parfor on 4 threads):

```
parfor i=1:N   
    idx = superpixels==i;
    bwF = bwmorph(idx,'dilate',10);
end
```

Does anyone know about any other MATLAB code that speeds up this process?

Thanks!

Comment: `imdilate` uses very efficient algorithms for computing the result.  If they're slow, then your problem is probably computationally burdening to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's Image Processing Toolbox includes Mathematical Morphology.
The dilation function is called [imdilate](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html). The toolbox uses the GPU for high speed.

Comment: I can not switch to GPU because I don't have a proper one.

Comment: You don't have to. It is an automatic option. It detects whether it is there and uses it if it is.

Comment: I'd argue that it actually doesn't "automatically" detect the GPU and use it when necessary.  The image processing toolbox uses the Intel Integrated Performance Primitives library to help accelerate computation, not using the GPU.  There is a separate mechanism for GPU processing with the image processing toolbox with use of `gpuArray`s.  You must explicitly create a `gpuArray` to use the GPU version of the image processing toolbox.

Comment: When I am trying to use gpuArray, I get the following error:  `The CUDA driver could not be loaded. An NVIDIA GPU with CUDA driver is required. The required CUDA version is: 4 or greater.
The library name used was: libcuda.so.1. The error was: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
directory.`

Comment: @user3517598 - Yes. `gpuArray`s are nVidia exclusive.  If you don't have a nVidia CUDA enabled card, `gpuArray`s are unfortunately not available.

Answer (score -1):

If you are searching for high performance image processing you should change to c++ and employ the GPU (CUDA for example). It's faster than using parallel cores of the cpu.

Comment: @ Eugenio Ivorra with gpuArray thats also possible in Matlab: http://de.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpuarray.html

Comment: @horseshoe Yes, you are absolutely right and moreover, you can even write custom CUDA code in C or C++ that you can run from MATLAB.

Comment: The problem is that my GPU is rather old and it is not an NVIDIA.